# Replicate TFS 2010 database on multiple site

Tags: sql-server

Developers are working in two different locations in differents countries, instead of having one TFS db in one location (and others connecting from another place), is it possible to have 2 replicated sites of TFS2010, each on a different server and some kind of nightly synchronisation?

Answer (score 2):

We support this [scenario with TFS Proxy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee248710.aspx). It stores a local cache of Version Control data on the remote location.

There is no counterpart for Work Items.

Replication is possible, because it is just a SQL Server feature. But you will have lots of conflicts during the synchronization. It is not a supported scenario, and not recommended.